# Angular - ngValue is not binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

`ngValue` will not bind the value unless you keep the reference of the same list. Is it correct?

This will not work:

```js
this.myForm.get('user').patchValue(this.currentUser);
```

This will work:

```js
const findIndex = this.user.findIndex(
  (item) => item.id == this.currentUser.id
);
this.myForm.get('user').patchValue(this.user[findIndex]);
```

Also, I came to one more property `compareWith` that can be used to bind as well.

This will work if I use it with `compareWith`.

```js
this.myForm.get('user').patchValue(this.currentUser);
```

Playground Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a4zbhn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `[compareWith]` Input property binding to the `<select>` element so that Angular could bind the value to the `<select>` by your defined comparison logic.

> .component.html

```
<select formControlName="user" [compareWith]="compare">
  <option *ngFor="let us of user" [ngValue]="us">{{ us.name }}</option>
</select>
```

> .component.ts

```js
compare(val1, val2) {
  return val1.id === val2.id;
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rguxr8?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

**Updated Remarks:**

As [Angular - SelectControlValueAccessor (Customizing option selection section)](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection) written,

> Angular uses object identity to select option.

Without `[compareWith]`, by default Angular will use *object reference* to select the option.

Hence your inference with the first method is correct and workable as long you are providing the object with the **exact reference** as the object(s) is existed in `[ngValue]`.

```js
const findIndex = this.user.findIndex(
    (item) => item.id == this.currentUser.id
);

this.myForm.get('user').patchValue(this.user[findIndex]);
```

---

### References

[Customizing option selection](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection)

Comment: What about the first question

Comment: Yes, for your first method works with `this.user[findIndex]`. As the link shared in **References**, *Angular uses object identity to select option*. Which means your inference on *ngValue will not bind the value unless you keep the reference of same list* is correct.